# @andorid In alertDialog custom listview, background color comes to black. I want white

Tags: android, listview, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to make custom list view AlertDialog. but the background color of Dialog is black.

and when I slide list, background color changes to white. I don't want to make my Dialog's

background black. What is problem?

```
btn_right.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            Dialog dialog2 = new Dialog(context); 
            ListView modeList = new ListView(context); 
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context); 
            SectionedAdapter adapter;  //custom adapter
            adapter = new SectionedAdapter(context);
                builder.setTitle("list"); 
                builder.setView(modeList);          
                adapter.addSection("7th", new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,
                        R.layout.member_list, R.id.member_text, stringList));
                modeList.setAdapter(adapter); 

                dialog2 = builder.create();
                dialog2.show();
```

Comment: add android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" in listview

Answer (score 3):

add below code:

`android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"` in listview

or

```
listview.setCacheColorHint(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
modeList.setCacheColorHint(0);
```